# Is there any way to show 0 when a select statement returns no data?

Tags: sql, db2

I have below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1
     ,date
     ,COUNT(*)
FROM table1                                                    
WHERE date = '2019-12-2'                                                        
GROUP BY col1, date  
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT col2
      ,date
      ,COUNT(*)
FROM table2                                                    
WHERE date = '2019-12-2'                                                        
GROUP BY col2, date
```

I want the result to show 0 if the second query comes with no data.
like:

```
Col1    date    15  
Col2    date    0
```

I tried to use case, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Where would it take data for `Col1` and `Col2` if there were no rows for `date = '2019-12-2'`?

Comment: Please tag with your RDBMS

Comment: If there is no rows for that date it will return nothing @GSerg

Comment: If it's okay to have nothing, then you don't need to do anything special to begin with, because that is the default behaviour. But you said you wanted a 0 instead of nothing.

Comment: You can't return just 0 as a result of 3-column result set. What should be returned in the 1-st and the 2-nd column in case of empty result set?

Comment: I mean Count(*) is 0, col1 is just label and the date is 2019-12-2

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like `IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0)`.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: The underlying problem isn't that the column is null (it's not - `COUNT(*)` doesn't produce `NULL`), it's that the row won't be present at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle 12 or higher, You may try below query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1
     ,date
     ,COUNT(*)
FROM table1                                                    
WHERE date = '2019-12-2'                                                        
GROUP BY col1, date  
UNION
(SELECT 'col2' col2
       ,'date' date
       ,'0' CNT
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DISTINCT col2
                ,date
                ,COUNT(*)
 FROM table2                                                    
 WHERE date = '2019-12-2'                                                        
 GROUP BY col2, date
 ORDER BY CNT DESC
 FETCH FIRST ONE ROW ONLY)
```

Similary For SQL-SERVER, Use TOP, For MySQL Use LIMIT 1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` clause for grouping.
The 2-nd part of `UNION ALL` may be rewritten as below. You may run this query as is to test it with different `WHERE` clauses.
Such a form of grouping adds an additional "total summary" record to the result set with the expression `GROUPING(COL2)=1 AND GROUPING(DATE)=1` which we use to distinguish this "additional" row from others. We show this record, if its `COUNT(*)=0` only, which indicates, that there are no groups returned.

```
SELECT 
  CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN 'COL2'      ELSE col2 END AS col2
, CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN '2019-12-2' ELSE date END AS date
, COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
VALUES 
  ('1', '2019-12-2')
, ('2', '2019-12-2')
) table2(col2, date)
WHERE 
date = '2019-12-2'
--date = '2019-12-1'
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((col2, date), ())
HAVING NOT (GROUPING(COL2)=1 AND GROUPING(DATE)=1 AND COUNT(*)<>0);
```

You may read more about `GROUPING SETS` in the [GROUP BY](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059209.html) clause description.